# Scrapy table with tr as header how to import it

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to import a table in scrapy which is organized as this:

```
<tr class="header1">
<tr class="row1">
<tr class="row2">
<tr class="row3">
<tr class="header2">
<tr class="row4">
```

And so on with different rows between the headers, how can i import the header so i have an item which the first attribute is the header name or text? Like

```
header1, row1
header1, row2
header1, row3
header2, row4
```

Comment: Please, show what you have tried so far and what was an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over "row" nodes and, for every node, get the *preceding "header" sibling*.

Imagine you have the following input HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="header1">HEADER 1</tr>
    <tr class="row1">ROW 1</tr>
    <tr class="row2">ROW 2</tr>
    <tr class="row3">ROW 3</tr>
    <tr class="header2">HEADER 2</tr>
    <tr class="row4">ROW 4</tr>
</table>
```

Now, here is how you can parse it:

```
>>> for row in response.css("tr[class^=row]"):
...     header_text = row.xpath("preceding-sibling::tr[starts-with(@class, 'header')][1]/text()").extract_first()
...     row_text = row.xpath("text()").extract_first()
...     print(header_text, row_text)
... 
(u'HEADER 1', u'ROW 1')
(u'HEADER 1', u'ROW 2')
(u'HEADER 1', u'ROW 3')
(u'HEADER 2', u'ROW 4')
```